# Timeout parallel executed thread

Tags: java, wait, synchronize

While dealing with parallel threads, the output should be:"wait, done"! Currently it is: "wait, not supposed to be shown ,done". Someone may help?
My main:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Supervisor a = new Supervisor();
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

The class Supervisor:

```
public class Supervisor {       
     public Supervisor()  { 
            Calculate t1 = new Calculate();
            t1.start(); 
            synchronized(t1){  
                System.out.println("wait");
                try {
                    t1.wait(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }           
        }   
    }
}
```

and the Calculator class:

```
public class Calculate extends Thread {
    public Calculate(){}

    @Override
    public void run() {
              synchronized(this){  
                  try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                        System.out.println("not supposed to be shown");
                    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }                   
                notify();
            }   
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `not supposed to be shown` should not be ... shown?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
        t1.start(); 
        synchronized(t1){
```

**could** result in `t1` getting to `run` before the `synchronized` section. Fix that like this:

```
        synchronized(t1){  
          t1.start();
```

There's also the documentation on [sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29):

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (**temporarily cease execution**) ...

Use this code and things look clearer:

```
public class Calculate extends Thread {

    public Calculate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Calc sleeping");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("not supposed to be shown");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            notify();
        }
    }
}

public class Supervisor {

    public Supervisor() {
        Calculate t1 = new Calculate();
        System.out.println("Super " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        synchronized (t1) {
            t1.start();
            System.out.println("wait");
            try {
                System.out.println("Super waiting");
                t1.wait(1000);
                System.out.println("Super awake");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("finish");
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Super main
wait
Super waiting
Calc sleeping
not supposed to be shown
Super awake
finish
```

See that when `Supervisor` sleeps, `Calculate` wakes up and runs to completion, taking 10 seconds, it then calls `notify` which wakes up `Supervisor` to continue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the supervisor must acquire the lock before `wait`'ing, but the calculator just releases the lock **after** the sleep and the println. You can easily see it yourself just by adding a breakpoint to the `println("not supposed")` and taking a thread dump of the JVM: the `main` thread, that runs the supervisor, is blocked in the constructor waiting for monitorentry (JVM jargon).

The bit

```
t1.start(); 
synchronized(t1) {
```

means that if the Calculator acuires the lock, the code inside the `synchronized` block in the supervisor is only executed when the lock is released (after the sleep). There are a number of issue with your code and it's not idiomatic, neither correct, so I give you the following reference

Supervisor:

```
Calculate calculator = new Calculate();
Thread thread = new Thread(calculator);
thread.start();

synchronized (calculator) {
    while (!calculator.completed) {
        calculator.wait(1000);
        if (!calculator.completed) {
            System.out.println("Supervisor here: waited 1s, still not ready");
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Computation ended and result consumed. Can rest :)");
```

Task

```
public class Calculate implements Runnable {

    public volatile boolean completed;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Calculator: Started!");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("Calculator: I'm done!");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        synchronized(this){
            completed = true;
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```